# Fail to fire window.onload event on IE when iframe load utf16 text file

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently run into an issue that when the web page include iframe loading utf16 text file. 
The page fail to fire window.onload event on IE7&8. I also try the jQuery method $(document).ready(), but it also can't work.
Firefox and chrome work well.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16" />
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  alert("test");
};
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/test/utf16.txt"  ></iframe>
</body></html>
```

The window.onload event is not triggered. How to fire “onload” event on IE for this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: There are some issues with IE like it doesn't pass referer on a pop-up window. This might be the same problem. Look into window.onload properties

Comment: did you try `<iframe onload="myOnloadFn()" src...>` ?